# Implementing Cordova plugin in Xcode project

Tags: swift, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

I do not understand how to implement a cordova plugin into my xcode project.  I have cordova and nodejs installed.  I am using swift 4

Here is the plugin I am trying to implement
https://github.com/rossmartin/cordova-plugin-ios-detect-screenshot

Comment: You might want to review what cordova is and what it is used for...  "Cordova wraps your HTML/JavaScript app into a native container which can access the device functions of several platforms. These functions are exposed via a unified JavaScript API, allowing you to easily write one set of code to target nearly every phone or tablet on the market today and publish to their app stores."